# How to allow the user to change certain text in a textpane?

Tags: java, swing

is there any way to allow the user to change certain text on a textpane in java? so for example if I have a textpane, like so;

```
textpane.setText("Please write your name here User, so it is easier for us to recognise");
```

How can I make it so that the user can change the text of 'User' to their name.

Comment: Can you give me example because i cannot understand you ? you want the user to change what? and where?

Comment: Will this allow the user to only change the User bit and nothing else?

Comment: So right now, textpane contains the text "Please write your name here User, so it is easier for us to recognise", I want the user to be able to change only the text 'User' to whatever their want and nothing else it editable by them.

Answer (score 1):

> "How can I make it so that the user can change the text of 'User' to their name."

Why do this at all? IMO it seems so user unfriendly, meaning the user may not know what you do. Using a text pane and asking the user to input will not by customary for the user.

I'd suggest maybe using a `JLabel` and a `JTextField`. Something like this

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;


public class UserFriendly {

    JLabel beginLabel;
    JLabel endLabel;
    JLabel message;
    JTextField nameField;
    String name = "";

    public UserFriendly() {
        beginLabel = new JLabel("Please write your name here");
        nameField = new JTextField(10);
        endLabel = new JLabel("so it is easier for us to recognise");
        message = new JLabel("Hello, ");

        JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
        p1.add(beginLabel);
        p1.add(nameField);
        p1.add(endLabel);
        nameField.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 2, 0, 2));

        message.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.CYAN, 5));
        message.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        message.setFont(new Font("helvitica", Font.BOLD, 16));

        nameField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                message.setText("Hello, " + nameField.getText());
            }

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                message.setText("Hello, " + nameField.getText());
            }

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            }

        });

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test Card");
        frame.add(p1);
        frame.add(message, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new UserFriendly();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

Also if you just set the background of the panel `p1` to white, it'll look just like a text field with no border. You could also set the border if you really want it to have a text field look.

```
// add to code above
p1.setBackground(Color.white);
p1.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1));
```

[image]

If you wanted to add a line at the bottom of the text field so its more apperent to the user where they should type, you could use a `MatteBorder` and just add a line to the bottom portion of the border.

```
p1.setBackground(Color.white);
p1.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1));
nameField.setBorder(new MatteBorder(0, 0, 1, 0, Color.BLACK));
```

[image]

Comment: This is a another way of doing it, but I wanted to know if its possible to allow the user to change certain parts of the textpane text. without having huge amount of code.

Comment: I don't think two labels and a text field is a huge amount of code.

Comment: Run through [these tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html) if you really want to go your route. But like I said, it seems user unfriendly

Comment: Also if you just set the background of the panel `p1`, it'll look just like a `text field` with nor border. You could also set the border if you really want it to have a text field look.

Answer (score 0):

Hej Peter,

if you only want to allow the user to change the given text try this

```
textPane.setText("Please write your name here User, so it is easier for us to recognise");
textPane.setEditable(true);
```

By setting the textpane editable, the user can change the text, but if it should be permanently changed, you have to save the user changed text after he is ready!

Patrick

Comment: but won't this allow the user to change any text within the textpane, I only want to allow the user to change the value of 'User' within this textpane.

Comment: Of cause, the solution of peeskillet is the better one.